# jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut race conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to handle a menu, where when you hover over an item, a box fades in, another item, another box fades in:

```
$( '.all' ).fadeOut( 'fast', function() { $( '#item' ).fadeIn( 'fast' );
```

but sometimes when you use the mouse too fast, multiple things show up or everything goes bye and usch.. how do I handle the race gracefully?

Comment: @TravisJ, semaphores in single-threaded code?

Comment: @lucero - Yup, although their use is primarily used for multi-threading, semaphores are used by definition to handle race conditions. Perhaps a spinning lock would work here.

Comment: I don't have time to search but this is a duplicate of multiple other questions

Comment: @TravisJ - or you could just use jQuery's `.stop()` method given that the overlapping animations are occurring within other jQuery code...

Comment: @nnnnnn - the .stop() method will leave pieces of menu everywhere unless it is used in conjunction with the queue which is most likely where the spinning lock would be implemented.

Comment: @TravisJ - The `.stop()` method works on the animation queue. In this case there won't be leftover pieces of menu because `.stop()` would be called immediately before queuing the appropriate `.fadeIn()` or `.fadeOut()`, i.e., to kill any in-progress animations before queuing more. Use jQuery's animation methods properly and you don't need to worry about your own semaphores or spinning locks or anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$( '.all' ).stop(true, true).fadeOut( 'fast', function() { $( '#item' ).stop(true, true).fadeIn( 'fast' );
```

`stop(true)` might be enough, hard to tell without seeing your html.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: thanks, i have more code, but really the above code is all I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try experimenting with the "queue" option. I'm not sure if it's available on the fadeIn function but you could try animating opacity with the animation function which does take a queue option.

$('.item').animate({opacity: 0}, {queue: false});